# building custom url validator - how to grab new url out of a 'moved' url response?

Tags: ruby, http

so I do this

```
require 'net/http';
require 'net/smtp';
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("http://www.cifs.dk"));
```

and `res.response.msg` tells me 302 - the site has moved.

How do I get the full address that it was moved to? `(http://www.cifs.dk/en)`

`res.methods` shows me a bunch of things to try but no luck yet.

The closest I've found is

`res.response.body`, but that just gives me

```
... </h1>This object may be found <a HREF="/en">here</a> ...
```

which would be no fun at all to try to piece together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) header is what you are looking for:

```
response['Location']
```

Comment: Thanks sir. That gives me "/en" instead of the whole url.On other sites, though, it gives the entire url. Is this normal, or did I just pick a freaky site? As a workaround, should I just look for "http" in the ['Location'] and if I don't find it, I trigger an append to the original url?

Comment: Yes, `/en` is the relative path. The location might be specified either as full URI or as relative path to the site root.